# Am I getting the right memory for my motherboard?

Tags: performance, memory, motherboard

I have a **Gigabyte GA-EP45-DS motherboard**. Also, the memory that came with my computer was two **Transcend aXe RAM 1066MHZ 1GB** modules.

The thing is, I noticed that my motherboard has "DDR2 1200" written on it. This concerns me, **have I bought slower memory than my computer is supposed to have ideally?** Now, I'm not super concerned at a granular level about the best optimal RAM with the best CAS latency etc... but I do hope at least that I've got the right speed.

Now, as far as I know, there is no such thing as ram at 1200MHZ? Am I right?

You see, because I'm thinking of getting more RAM now, before I can't find the same type or speed any-more and just want to make sure it's the right thing. Furthermore, if the memory is slower than what I should be getting for my motherboard, what RAM should I be getting, and will that new RAM play nice with my old RAM? If I get new RAM at a different speed, would it be better / more beneficial performance-wise to omit the old RAM because of how the whole DUAL channel RAM thing works? I'm not too clued up on this area. Thanks chiefs.

Comment: Hello, anyone out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While DDR2 1200 is not a standard speed, boutique overclocker's RAM is rated at whatever the manufacturer feels they can assure the user it will go to.

Unless you are invoking the overlocking options on your Motherboard, you are most likely running your memory at 1066MHz.

Comment: So basically, 1066MHz RAM would be the correct memory to get for the motherboard?

Comment: If you are not planning on overclocking, yes.